# Batch programming name display

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:start
set CTR=1
:loop
echo Lanz
set /a ctr=%CTR%+1
if ctr LEQ 5( 
    echo Lanz
) else goto loop
if ctr==5 goto finish
:finish
echo %CTR%
pause
cls
goto start
```

I just need help on this.
The instruction is that it needs to display the name five times in a loop statement form.

It's difficult because what my teacher gave me is a flowchart, I followed everything to the letter, it's not working. Help

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a for loop?

```
@echo off

for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
  echo Lanz
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `goto`, it might look similar to this:

```
@echo off
set ctr=1
:loop
echo Lanz
set /a ctr=%ctr%+1
if %ctr% LEQ 5 goto loop
echo %ctr%
pause
```

There's no need for other labels and gotos: simple as `do ... while`